# How to add music to my iPhone while Apple Music and iCloud Music Library are enabled?

Tags: itunes, icloud

Hi I was trying to get some music into my iPhone through iTunes and it just doesn't seem to work? I've looked it up online and it just says drag and drop files but it doesn't work for me. I have Apple Music and iCloud Music Library enabled. Does this mean that now I can't download music and put it on my iPhone?

I also found same question here but it's from 2015 has anything changed since that?

Comment: "says drag and drop files" Says where? That's never been how iTunes syncs. It syncs from your iTunes Library with options you set up in the iTunes sync pages. Please provide links to the documentation/questions you have been referring to.

Comment: @Tetsujin sure thing https://www.lifewire.com/manual-music-syncing-from-itunes-2438646 step 6. However I don't believe this is helpful with my question here.